# Using topology to characterize embedded Lie subgroups of Lie groups.

Tags: lie-groups, gn.general-topology

Cartan's theorem states that any topologically closed subgroup of a Lie group is an embedded Lie subgroup.

This leads us to ask the following question:

> Can we replace "topologically closed" with a different topological property and achieve the same result? For instance, is a semi-locally simply connected subgroup of a Lie group an embedded Lie subgroup?  Is a locally connnected and semi-locally simply connected subgroup of a Lie group an embedded Lie subgroup?

Some observations:
An arcwise connected subgroup of a Lie group is not always an embedded Lie subgroup. For instance, consider the following example taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_subgroup:

"...take G to be a torus of dimension ≥ 2, and let H be a one-parameter subgroup of irrational slope, i.e. one that winds around in G. Then there is a Lie group homomorphism φ : R → G with H as its image. The closure of H will be a sub-torus in G."

This example is an arc-wise connected (but not locally connected) subgroup of a Lie group that is not an embedded Lie subgroup. The issue is that in the definition of an embedded Lie subgroup you require that the subgroup be nice with respect to the subset topology, in order for the Lie subgroup to be an embedded submanifold. See the section on embedded submanifolds in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold

So whatever topological constraint we use to replace "closed" it has to be stronger than arcwise-connectedness.

Comment: At the risk of asking a silly question: why would you expect "semi-locally simply connected" to be able to replace "closed"?  The only ever time I've come across that property is in the theorem about the existence of universal coverings, but probably I'm missing something...


Comment: Thanks for the question. My explanation is that Lie subgroups locally look like a single plane. So one might expect that as long as we rule out "local disconnectivity" and "small loops" we might have a subgroup that locally resembles a plane enough to be a Lie subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I believe that this condition is known.  (See below for a possible answer.)


Comment: I think in general the word "Lie subgroup" should _not_ mean "embedded Lie subgroup".  Rather, "embedded Lie subgroup" should continue to carry that extra adjective.  The reason for preferring this terminology is because there is a bijection between Lie subalgebras of the Lie algebra of a give Lie group G and (immersed, but not embedded) connected Lie subgroups of G.  But as the irrational line in the torus shows, not every Lie subalgebra integrates to an embedded Lie subgroup.  But anyway, the question of when subgroups _are_ embedded Lie is a good one.

Comment: I believe I have seen the terminology "Virtual Lie Subgroup" for the sitation where we have an immersion like the irrational slope subgroup. See "maths.dept.shef.ac.uk/magic/course_files/43/…;. I personally don't like the word, but it could be a useful mnemonic to say "beware: the group topology for the subgroup is not generally the same as the relative topology inherited from the surrounding group". 

Comment: To avoid a "messy" immersion is I guess why some authors require a matrix group to be a closed subgroup of gl(n, K); I can see why this might be done in a first course, but Rossman's treatment (see comment after second answer below) does not make this requirement, IMHO better for thus being less cluttered and the situation really isn't more more complicated: you just have to be careful about which topology you are talking about.

Comment: Even if it is not the same question, the problem seems related to
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63868/is-every-lie-subgroup-of-glv-isomorphic-to-a-maybe-another-closed-subgroup-of/63890#63890

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
This does not actually answer the question.  I do not assume that Lie subgroups are embedded submanifolds, whereas the OP does.

---

I believe that this question has a classical answer.  In Knapp's [review](http://www.mathstat.uottawa.ca/~rossmann/Lie_book_files/BakerRossmann.pdf) of Wulf Rossmann's book [Lie groups: an introduction through linear groups](http://www.mathstat.uottawa.ca/~rossmann/Lie_book.htm), he mentions that this problem was solved by Chevalley in the 1940s and the condition is that of what Chevalley called an *analytic subgroup*.  Despite the name, the notion is topological.

Analytic subgroups are precisely those which are connected in what Rossmann calls the *group topology*.  This is the topology generated by the image under the exponential map of the $\epsilon$-balls in the Lie algebra.  In other words, a subset $U$ of a Lie group $G$ is open if and only if for every $a \in U$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the set
$$ \left\lbrace a \exp(X)  \mid \|X\|<\epsilon \right\rbrace $$
is contained in $U$.

(The asymmetry in the definition is fictitious: either $a\exp(X)$ or $\exp(X) a$ define the same topology.)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I am asking for another form of Cartan's theorem. Let H be a subgroup of a Lie group G. In Cartan's theorem the topological property, closed, refers to H with the subset topology from G. I am not asking for you to invent a new topology (I ruled out irrationally sloped lines on a flat torus, which are analytic subgroups but not Lie subgroups).

Recall that stating that H is Lie subgroup of G means more than just that H is a Lie group that is also a subgroup of G. Please see the wikipedia article
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_subgroup
for a complete definition.

Comment: Why would you want to rule out the irrationally sloped lines on the torus?  They are perfectly good Lie subgroups.  In fact, you don't get a good version of the inverse Lie correspondence unless you take such subgroups into account.  The lesson from Chevalley's work, in my opinion, is that demanding that the subgroups be embedded submanifolds is too restrictive.

Comment: I added "embedded" in front of Lie subgroup. The reason why I ask this is because I am curious of whether there are other versions of Cartan's theorem.

Comment: Fair enough.  My answer is then not relevant.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** This answer is invalid to the question because the OP wanted embedded submanifolds.  I'm leaving the answer up because it does handle a related question and contains a reference to a paper.

An arcwise connected subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie subgroup at least in the analytic case; cf. [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2035979).  I recall that it's in the appendix to volume 1 of Kobayashi and Nomizu's *Foundations of Differential Geometry.*

Comment: I added a few observations to the question. On your post: I don't believe this answers the question. Please let me know if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Perhaps we are using different definitions of a Lie subgroup.  In my case, I allowed immersions and not just embeddings.  I'm not sure, but I think you're looking only for embedded ones.  Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Whoops! Then this answer is indeed invalid.  I'll leave it up in case anyone else finds it interesting as a random tidbit of differential geometry and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

For analytic subgroups (that is immersed and connected) to be embedded (i.e. to be a regular submanifold) is equivalent to being topologically closed. This equivalence is true only for Lie groups. In one sense this is Cartan's theorem.I dont remember exactly the proof of the converse, but is something like this: if $H$ is an embedded Lie subgroup its closure K is a closed subgroup, hence  embedded too. If the dimension of K is greater than that of H there is a contradiction because in regular submanifolds you can take charts with an isolated slice... I guess this is done in Warner's book.